# Gmaps4Rails V2, adding circle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

Rails n00b here.  I'm attempting to add circles to my maps and stuck on adding this functionality.  My current view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      circle = [{'lng' => <%= @listing.longitude %>, 'lat' => <%= @listing.latitude %>, 'radius' => 25000, 'strokeColor' => '#FF0000'}]
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.addCircle(circle);
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
      handler.getMap().setZoom(12);
    }); </script>
```

The map is working correctly when I remove the "circle= ..." code as well as handler.addCircle(circle) code.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `circle =` should probably be in JS hash syntax like:

```
 circle = [{lng: <%= @listing.longitude %>, lat: <%= @listing.latitude %>, radius: 25000, strokeColor: "#FF0000"}]
```

You currently have it in Ruby syntax.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That change, in conjunction with changing handler.addCircle(circle) to handler.addCircles(circle), solved the problem.  Now I just need to figure out how to adjust the zoom based on the user-set radius!